# Managing content of android app

Tags: android

For a simple app that has a list of (for example) stores, how are the CRUD operations implemented? Would a desktop/web manager app be the solution?

For example, the manager has all the CRUD implementations while the mobile app just displays and process search queries.

EDIT:

Lets say I am making an application for android that shows users where the best vegetables can be obtained within a 10 mile radius, such application would only have a list of stores, a search bar and perhaps a simple sistem for more narrow queries (like the organic etc...)

Naturally I'll want to add, edit and delete the record of stores that the app shows, but I don't want to even show a link or option to manage the app on the user interface for security reasons.

I was considering building a basic desktop app that manages the CRUD operations, whereas the mobile one just periodically updates the information to reflect changes if any.

This is my first mobile app so I am not quite sure how this is often deal with.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this question is very contextual. The answer is, it depends!

Is the data meant to exist only on the application itself? If so, I'd look into [sqllite](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) database management.

Is the data meant to be used on a web application aswell? If so I'd look into implementations  such as [parse](https://www.parse.com/) (and many others) that will handle the persisting of the data.

Perhaps you have the data on the database already, maybe your next step is building a restful api to interact with said data

Comment: thanks for the reply, allow me a second to elaborate on the question.